# Spring boot and maven build number plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 2.0.5,and added code to generate build number using maven build number plugin.  The build number is generating fine. I can see on jar and in the builNumber.properties file but its not being substituted in finalName in version.txt file.

Additional details:

Here is my POM.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>buildNumber</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <format>{0,number}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>buildNumber</item>
                </items>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
</build>
```

I have created version.txt file in resources folder and it has following text.

```
@project.build.finalName@
```

On maven clean install this file is updated in target folder. In below logs line # 2 you can see build number is added to jar file name.

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ try ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/ubuntu/Spring/SpringBootData-REST/target/try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.10.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ try ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ try ---
[INFO] Installing /home/ubuntu/Spring/SpringBootData-REST/target/try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.10.jar to /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/try/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/ubuntu/Spring/SpringBootData-REST/pom.xml to /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/try/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But buildNumber is not replaced in version.txt. 
Here is how it looks after maven clean install.

```
try-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.${buildNumber}
```

Here is buildNumber.properties file with the buildNumber.

```
#maven.buildNumber.plugin properties file
#Sat Mar 09 11:51:51 CST 2019
buildNumber=10
```

Can you point out whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a workaround. 
Changed my Version.txt to below instead of @project.build.finalName@ and its working fine now.

```
@project.artifactId@
@project.version@
@buildNumber@
```

Output

```
SpringBootDataRest
1.0
15
```